# Ng-Submit does not sumbit form

Tags: angularjs, ng-submit

I am trying to call a function on ng-submit to push to an array if I console log the function it clearly works its just on button event the ng-submit does not get called. I have been researching this issue for far to long. I created a codepen for the problem.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emVGNb

```
<html lang="en">
 <body ng-app="meanDemo">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="mainCtrl as main">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="meetup in main.meetups">
            {{ meetup.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


<form ng-submit="main.createMeetup()">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Meetup Name" ng-model="main.meetupName">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
angular.module('meanDemo', []);

angular.module('meanDemo').controller('mainCtrl', function(){

var vm = this;
vm.meetups = [ { name: 'Ralphs Meetup'}];

vm.createMeetup = function(){
    console.log('hello');
    vm.meetups.push({ name: vm.meetupName });
    vm.meetups.push({ name: 'bobs meetup' });
    vm.meetupName = " "
}


vm.createMeetup();
console.log(vm.meetups)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your form is outside the div that has your `ng-controller` attribute. Therefore the form is not connected the your `mainCtrl` controller and has no access to the `createMeetup` function.

Here's a code snippet, all you need to do, really, is move the form inside the div with the `ng-controller` attribute:

```js
angular.module('meanDemo', []);

angular.module('meanDemo').controller('mainCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.meetups = [{
    name: 'Ralphs Meetup'
  }];

  vm.createMeetup = function() {
    console.log('hello');
    vm.meetups.push({
      name: vm.meetupName
    });
    vm.meetups.push({
      name: 'bobs meetup'
    });
    vm.meetupName = " "
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="meanDemo">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="mainCtrl as main">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="meetup in main.meetups">
        {{ meetup.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>

    <form ng-submit="main.createMeetup()">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Meetup Name" ng-model="main.meetupName">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I just spent so much time trying to figure it out that I over looked that div tag... Thanks for the extra eyes!